# important separators

Tags: graphs, minimum-cuts

Given a graph G and an important (X,Y)-separator S, why is it true that for every edge e in S the set of S\e is an important (X,Y)-separator in G\e

Important (X,Y) cut is defined as follows:
S is an important (X,Y)-cut if it is inclusion-wise minimal and there is no (X,Y)-cut S' with $|S'|<=|S|$ such that R' dominates R where R,R' are the sets of vertices reachable from X in $G/S, G/S'$ respectively.

I understand that this is a basic claim in the proof of bounding important separators at $4^k$ and I somewhat understand the logic that every other edge disjoint path doesn't contain e but I'm stumbled here

I'm doing a presentation on important separators based on [https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Emalcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf)
book at chapter 8.

It's stated as Proposition 8.9 and given as exercise. (I'm just trying to get the logic behind this claim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that $S\setminus e$ is not an important separator in $G\setminus e$. In other words, there exists a cut $S'$ in $G\setminus e$ with $|S'|<|S\setminus e|$ and $R'\supset R$. Now, observe that $S'\cup\{e\}$ must be a cut in $G$ with $|S'\cup\{e\}|<|S|$ and $R'\supset R$. But that implies that $S$ is not an important separator in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Any chances you could help me with second part of the claim?
It states that if $S$ is also $(X',Y)$ cut for $X′⊃X$ then it's important as well

Comment: I suppose what you mean is that $S$ is then important for $(X',Y)$. I think what is easiest to do here is a direct proof from the fact that $S$ is a minimal cut. You can easily see that if $S$ is minimal, then every component of $G\setminus S$ contains at least one vertex from either $X$ or $Y$ (since it doesn't cut away any part of the graph that didn't "need to" be cut). Therefore $R$ is the union of all components in $G\setminus S$ that don't contain a vertex from $Y$. But if $S$ separates $X'$ and $Y$, then $X'\subseteq R$, and the proof follows from there.

Comment: I am sorry, I was a little inaccurate in the previous comment. I should say that every component of $G\setminus S$ *that belongs to a component of $G$ that contains at least one vertex from $X$ or $Y$* also contains at least one vertex from $X$ or $Y$.